# Toggle images on beforeChange event with Slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I am trying to figure out how to show and hide some images depending on the clicked element with one of the events of Slick.

```
<div class="items" id="icons-tabs">

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item iconClicked" data-tab="tab0">
            <img src="/researchicon.png" alt="" class="img-active">
            <img src="/researchKOSelected.svg" alt="" class="img-inactive">
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item iconClicked" data-tab="tab1">
            <img src="/WideRange.png" alt="" class="img-active">
            <img src="/WideRangeUpSelected.svg" alt="" class="img-inactive">
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item iconClicked" data-tab="tab2">
            <img src="/SSI_toolbox.png" alt="" class="img-active">
            <img src="/toolboxKOSelected.svg" alt="" class="img-inactive">
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item iconClicked" data-tab="tab3">
            <img src="/PricingIcon.png" alt="" class="img-active">
            <img src="/PricingIconUpSelected.svg" alt="" class="img-inactive">
        </a>

</div>
```

As you see in that markup, there are some images with the class `img-active` which are the images that the user will see when the document is ready.

***That set of images looks like this:***
[image]

All I need is that when you click over the image, it must hide the current one and show the image with the class `img-inactive`, so it must be like a kind swap of classes between `img-inactive` and `img-active`.

This what I have done so far:

```
$mobSlick.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    $('a[data-tab="tab'+nextSlide+'"] > img')
        .first()
        .addClass('img-inactive')
        .removeClass('img-active');

    $('a[data-tab="tab'+currentSlide+'"] > img')
        .first()
        .addClass('img-active')
        .removeClass('img-inactive');

    $('a[data-tab="tab'+nextSlide+'"] > img')
        .not(":eq(0)")
        .addClass('img-active')
        .removeClass('img-inactive');

    $('a[data-tab="tab'+currentSlide+'"] > img')
        .not(":eq(0)")
        .addClass('img-inactive')
        .removeClass('img-active');
});
```

The problem with this code is that it works almost fine when you click the items from left to right, but when you do it from right to left or with no order at all, it crashes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @mjw I am trying to use the slicker events in order to hide and show some images when the user navigates among the sliders. It is a very big component. Not sure if I can reproduce in a simple fiddle. It is something very specific.

Comment: if each slide is tied with the #icon-tabs why not use slick index and query the element based on that index?

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way too hard.

First of all, inline javascript (`href="javascript:void(0)"`) is not a good tactic and you should use [Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) to make sure it's not run any inline stuff.

Second I believe what you want is way too simple for the script you have written. You just need to insert `style="display:none;"` on img-inactive images and the following jquery code.

```
`$('.iconClicked').click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
});`
```

Then again you could insert some animation to it, like fade. To do that you should position the images absolutely, so each pair is on the same spot. You add transition on the opacity attribute of the images and with jquery you toy with opacity as needed.

If you simultaneously set one to opacity 1 and the other to 0, then the images will be semitransparent for a while. To prevent this, you should set one image to opacity 1 and set a timer (with setTimout) to then change the other to 0.

### Edit:

You can also use `toggleClass('img-active img-inactive');` instead of plain toggle(). This will interchange the classes. I vaguely understand your exact problem, so if this does not answer your question, maybe you should give some more info.

Comment: Yes, it works that way. But if I click on one image, I need the rest of the images to be in its default shape. Only the current image should have the new class in it.

Comment: Check this example: https://www.screencast.com/t/bDoGfWXlRh the current  clicked image is blue and the rest in its default shape.

Comment: And I am doing it like that because I depend on the event of the slick slider. So this way it won't work!